# MvvmCross - Setting EditText to void doesn't update ViewModelProperty

Tags: android, android-edittext, mvvmcross

I have a problem with Android `editText` and MvvmCross.
When I set the `editText` (which contains a number) to void (with delete) it doesn't affect the ViewModel Property.

It doesn't depend on my code, it can be reproduce in the api example of MVVMCross :

AXML :

```
<TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Enter a number..." />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text DoubleProperty" />
```

ViewModel :

```
private double _doubleProperty = 42.12;

public double DoubleProperty
{
    get { return _doubleProperty; }
    set { _doubleProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => DoubleProperty); }
}
```

[screenshot from API Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODa8Q.png)

Comment: Can you show your axml and viewmodel code for this editText/property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is around the `DoubleProperty` having a non nullable type of `double`, therefore it can not be 'Void' of value. Simply changing your double type to a nullable double will not work either. It will fail at setting the empty string to the nullable double:

> MvxBind:Error: 44.49 SetValue failed with exception -
>   ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted
>   to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Double]'.

So how can you get it working?

**Approach 1 - Allow null values**

One approach that I have used before it to use an `MvxValueConverter` to convert the empty string into a null value.

```
public class NullableDoubleToStringConverter : MvxValueConverter<double?, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(double? value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    protected override double? ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double outValue;
        return double.TryParse(value, out outValue) ? (double?)outValue : null;
    }
}
```

In your `ViewModel` change the type to nullable:

```
private double? _doubleProperty = 42.12;
public double? DoubleProperty
{
    get { return _doubleProperty; }
    set { _doubleProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => DoubleProperty); }
}
```

In your `AXML/XML` use your converter:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text NullableDoubleToString(DoubleProperty)" />
```

**Approach 2 - Default to Zero (not null)**

This approach will reset the value to 0 when removing the last current value in the editText.

Converter:

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : MvxValueConverter<double, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(double value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    protected override double ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ? default(double) : double.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

ViewModel property:

```
private double _doubleProperty = 42.12;
public double DoubleProperty
{
    get { return _doubleProperty; }
    set { _doubleProperty = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => DoubleProperty); }
}
```

Layout `AXML/XML`:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text DoubleToString(DoubleProperty)" />
```